# Rename error: "The file is already being used by another process"

Tags: python, file, rename

Good evening !

This is my first code, I'm having trouble renaming a file because I get a WinError error 32] The file is already being used by another process because of PyPDF2, and I don't know how to solve it, I already tried to put a repeat or if.

```py
import PyPDF2
import os

for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/luan.carvalho/Downloads/"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        global Files_CSV
        Files_CSV = os.path.join("C:/Users/luan.carvalho/Downloads/", file)
        # print(Files_CSV)
        pdf_file = open(Files_CSV, "rb")
        read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        parsed = "".join(page_content)
        parsed = re.sub("n", "", parsed)
        global novastring
        novastring = parsed[619:673]
        print(novastring)
        file_oldname = os.path.join(Files_CSV)
        file_newname_newfile = os.path.join(
            "C:/Users/luan.carvalho/Downloads/", novastring.replace(" ", "") + ".pdf"
        )
        print(file_oldname)
        os.rename(file_oldname, file_newname_newfile)
```

error

```
An exception occurred: PermissionError
[WinError 32] The file is already being used by another process: 'C:/Users/luan.carvalho/Downloads/1611.pdf' -> 'C:/Users/luan.carvalho/Downloads/35211156992951003679550060000016111717241010.pdf'
   File "C:\Users\luan.carvalho\OneDrive - Solistica\Escritorio\import PyPDF2.py", line 35, in <module>
     os.rename(file_oldname, file_newname_newfile)
```

Comment: At the point where your code tries to rename the file, it is still open for reading because  of `pdf_file = open(Files_CSV, "rb")` and there is no corresponding call to `pdf_file.close()`. It's  important to close files (and other OS resources) when you are done with them.

Comment: I suggest to let PyPDF2.PdfReader handle the file opening. Just give PdfReader the path.

Comment: By the way, [PyPDF2 updated the syntax quite a bit](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/blob/main/CHANGELOG#L353-L472)